# Join two tables and get newest entry in two tables depends on the updated date of two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have `fixedassets` and `fixedassets_history` tables.

In the `fixedassets` table, there are `id`, `purchase_date`, `purchase_price`, `updated_date`.

In `fixedassets_history` table, there are `fixedassets_id`, `description`, `updated_date`.

I join these tables with `id`. I want to retrieve the recent updated records from these tables according to `fixedassets`'s `update_date` field and `fixedassets_history`'s `updated_date` in MySQL.

This is my SQL script:

```
SELECT fa.*,fh.text,fh.date  
FROM fixedassets fa 
JOIN fa_history fh ON fa.id=fh.fixedassets_id 
ORDER BY fa.updated_date desc,fh.date desc  limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
fa.id,
max(fa.updated_date) , 
fa.other_column
from fixedassets fa 
left join (
            select 
                fixedassets_id , 
                max(updated_date) , 
                other_columns 
                from fixedassets_history
            ) as fah on fah.fixedassets_id = fa.id
group by fa.id
```